# Is there an efficient way to version on modification in AEM

Tags: aem

We'd like to implement a process that creates a version of the page or asset whenever that object is modified. Is there a way to set this up in CQ5 ootb or will this require a custom event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to get a lot of versions happening, as a modification event is flung every time a component is altered in context, or by dialog. It's the same with rollout on modification and puts a lot of load on the author.

I would also be thinking about the disk space it will use up.

You can set up a workflow that fires on modification, and in there, use the CreateVersioningProcess step to take a version snapshot.

Alternately, if you wanted to concatenate modifications based on time or some other metric, then a custom event handler would be the approach I would take.

Comment: As a follow up, after proto-typing a version on modification. This was deemed way to noisy as a single change of a field could result in several versions. I ended up implementing a two-phase approach where I created a listener that would tag the page with a property indicating that it needs to be versioned, then a second process that could be scheduled to take all these pages and version them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to AEM but I've been working in the IT industry during last 25 years. My advice would be to implement a JCRlistener within AEM and to persist this information (i.e. modification of a node with/without filtering) on a different system (DBMS).

I was able to implement the listener fairly easily as an OSGI bundle (although I experienced some problems with the bind and unbind methods). Please find a complete (persistency not included) and working Java class below:

```
    package com.dlwconsulting.mywebsite;

import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.observation.Event;
import javax.jcr.observation.EventIterator;
import javax.jcr.observation.EventListener;
import javax.jcr.observation.ObservationManager;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.*;

import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingConstants;

import org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Dictionary;

@Component(immediate=true, metatype=false, description = "Wim's JCRListener")
@Service
public class JCRListenerImplementator implements EventListener{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JCRListenerImplementator.class);
    private Session session;
    private ObservationManager observationManager;

    private static final String NODE_TREE = "/content/geometrixx-outdoors";

    @Reference
    private SlingRepository slingRepository;

    // @Reference(policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC, cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY)
    // private SlingRepository slingRepository;

    /* public void bindEventAdmin (EventAdmin eventAdmin) {
        this.eventAdmin = eventAdmin;
    }

    public void unbindEventAdmin() {
        this.eventAdmin = null;
    } */

    public void bindSlingRepository (SlingRepository slingRepository) {
        this.slingRepository = slingRepository;
    }

    public void unbindSlingRepository(SlingRepository slingRepository) {
        this.slingRepository = null;
    }

    @Activate
    public void start() {
        LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: started JCRListenerImplementator.activate()");

        try {
            LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: Inside Try!");
            session = slingRepository.loginAdministrative(null);
            if (slingRepository.getDescriptor(SlingRepository.OPTION_OBSERVATION_SUPPORTED).equals("true")) {
                observationManager = session.getWorkspace().getObservationManager();
                // final String[] types = {"nt:unstructured","sling:OrderedFolder"};
                // final String path = "/content/customer";
                observationManager.addEventListener(this, Event.NODE_ADDED,         NODE_TREE, true, null, null, false);
                observationManager.addEventListener(this, Event.PROPERTY_CHANGED,   NODE_TREE, true, null, null, false);
                LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware : EventListeners added");
            }
            else {
                LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware : No OBSERVATION SUPPORTED");
            }
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Exception in JCRListenerImplementator.activate()");
            // throw new RepositoryException (e);
        }

    }

    @Deactivate
    public void stop() {
        LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: started JCRListenerImplementator.deactivate()");
        try {
            if(observationManager != null) {
                observationManager.removeEventListener(this);
            }
            if (session != null) {
                session.logout();
                session = null;
            }
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Exception in JCRListenerImplementator.activate()");
            // throw new RepositoryException (e);
        }
    }

    // @Reference
    // private EventAdmin eventAdmin;

    /** The job topic for my events. */
    public static final String JOB_TOPIC = "com/sling/eventing/WimsTopic";

    // @Override
    public void onEvent(EventIterator events) {
        LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: started JCRListenerImplementator.onEvent()");
        while(events.hasNext()){
            Event e = events.nextEvent();
            try {
                LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: Event " + e.getPath() + " has occurred!");
                LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: >>>Event Identifier = " + e.getIdentifier());
                LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: >>>Event UserData = " + e.getUserData());
                LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: >>>Event date = " + e.getDate());
                LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: >>>Event type = " + e.getType());
                Map<String, Object> m = e.getInfo();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : m.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    Object value = entry.getValue();
                    LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: >>>Event Info Key = " + key);
                    LOGGER.info(">>>Delaware: >>>Event Info Value = " + value);
                }

                final Dictionary<String,Object> properties = new Hashtable();
                properties.put("name", "my name");
                properties.put("description", "my description");
                properties.put("path", e.getPath());

            } catch (RepositoryException e1) {
                LOGGER.info("Exception in JCRListenerImplementator.onEvent()");
            }
        } // end while
    } // end method


}
```

Comment: I agree with the utilization of the Listener, but storing the information in a second data store defeats the usefulness of the version system. The current version system allows direct access by the authors so that they can go back and recover work or revert to a prior point in time, all through the authoring interface.